# Visual Studio 2015, any way to use Enter to accept Intellisense completion suggestion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The default to accept a suggested auto-completion from Intellisense is the Tab key.  Is there a way to either change this key-binding or at least to add the option to use the Enter key as well for the same purpose?

The language is C# though I don't know how relevant that is to the question.

Comment: FYI, I can use ENTER key to accept auto-completion option in my VS2015 with default setting.

Comment: I believe both the TAB and ENTER key do the same thing on Intellisense. Although I can't be sure, cause whatever it is, is just naturally rolls off my fingers now.

Comment: It could be true that ENTER is also a default (and would also explain why my muscle memory is so strong to use it).  I did install XKeymacs recently in order to get emacs key bindings.  I wonder if that might have broken it.